# ¿Cómo minifico mi archivo CSS correctamente?

Tags: javascript, html, css, gulp

Estoy trabajando con **GULP** y tengo una funcion que minifica mis archivos .css que tengo.

Cuando  modifico mi archivo **css**, teniendo gulp corriendo, este hace que entre en un loop infinito.
Haciendo que los archivos generados (.min.css) se sobreescriban  una y otra vez.

Dejo mi codigo gulp para que lo revisen

No sé que ocurre ¿podrían ayudarme?

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var cssMin = require('gulp-clean-css');
var min = require('gulp-uglify');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');



function Default () {

   js();

   browserSync.init({ 
          server: "./src"
         });

 gulp.watch('src/sass/*.scss', Sass);
 gulp.watch("src/*.html").on('change',browserSync.reload);
 gulp.watch('src/css/*.css',MinifyCss);

 }
function Sass(){

 return gulp.src('src/sass/*.scss')
.pipe(sass()) //le decimos que vamos a convertir nuestro archivo sass 
.pipe(gulp.dest("src/css")) //le dcemos que lo guarde aquí
.pipe(browserSync.stream());
 }

function MinifyCss(){
   return gulp.src(['src/css/style.css','src/css/bootstrap.css'])
   .pipe(cssMin())
   .pipe(rename({suffix:'.min'}))
   .pipe(gulp.dest('src/css'));
}


 function js(){
   return gulp.src(['node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js',
'node_modules/@popperjs/core/dist/umd/popper.js'])
.pipe(gulp.dest("src/js"))
.pipe(browserSync.stream());
}

function MinifyJs(){
return gulp.src(['node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js',
'node_modules/@popperjs/core/dist/umd/popper.js'])
.pipe(min())
.pipe(rename({suffix:'.min'}))
.pipe(gulp.dest('src/js'));
}

exports.default = Default;
```

Adjunto imágenes del loop infinito
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
también me suelta un error pero no  sé que signifique
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué comando ejecutas o cómo tienes configurada la build?

Comment: El mismo de siempre: gulp, que ejecuta mi default